# Syntax error. Unexpected 'if'

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I want to select one of the genders in the select option when **$row["gender"] == select option**. The only way to do this i think is through if else statement, but in this case, 'if' creates error. I think my syntax might be wrong or is it because of the single and double quote?

```
$output .= '  
                <tr class="datas">  
                     <td class="id" data-id10="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["id"].'</td>
                     <td class="firstname" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["firstname"].'</td>  
                     <td class="middlename" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["middlename"].'</td>  
                     <td class="lastname" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["lastname"].'</td> 
                     <td class="address" data-id4="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["address"].'</td> 
                     <td class="gender" data-id5="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>

                     <select onchange="getval(this)">

                     'if ($row["gender"]=="Male") {
                         echo '<option value="Male" selected>Male</option>
                     <option value="Female">Female</option>';
                     } else if ($row["gender"]=="Female") {
                       echo '<option value="Male">Male</option>
                     <option value="Female" selected>Female</option>';
                     } .'

                     </select>

                     </td> 

                     <td class="contact" data-id6="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["contact"].'</td> 
                     <td class="username" data-id7="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["username"].'</td> 
                     <td class="password" data-id8="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["password"].'</td> 

                     <td class="but"><button type="button" name="delete_btn" id="delete_btn" data-id9="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">DELETE</button>
                      <button type="button" name="delete_btn" id="update_btn" data-id12="'.$row["id"].'">UPDATE</button>
                      </td>
                </tr>  
           ';
```

Comment: You cannot use `if` when concatenating a string. Use multiple statements or a ternary expression instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to rewrite part of Your code like this:

```
$output = ' ...
<select onchange="getval(this)">
    <option value="Male" ' . ( $row["gender"]=='Male' ? 'selected' : '' ) . '>Male</option>
    <option value="Female" ' . ( $row["gender"]=='Female' ? 'selected' : '' ) . '>Female</option>
</select> ...'
```

[Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: thanks. this works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 1):

Split your code to multiple statements:

```
$output .= '  
<tr class="datas">  
    <td class="id" data-id10="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["id"].'</td>
    <td class="firstname" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["firstname"].'</td>  
    <td class="middlename" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["middlename"].'</td>  
    <td class="lastname" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["lastname"].'</td> 
    <td class="address" data-id4="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["address"].'</td> 
    <td class="gender" data-id5="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>
    <select onchange="getval(this)">
     ';
if ($row["gender"]=="Male") {
    $output .= '<option value="Male" selected>Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>';
} else if ($row["gender"]=="Female") {
    $output .= '<option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female" selected>Female</option>';
}
$output .= '
        </select>
    </td> 

    <td class="contact" data-id6="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["contact"].'</td> 
    <td class="username" data-id7="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["username"].'</td> 
    <td class="password" data-id8="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["password"].'</td> 

    <td class="but"><button type="button" name="delete_btn" id="delete_btn" data-id9="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">DELETE</button>
    <button type="button" name="delete_btn" id="update_btn" data-id12="'.$row["id"].'">UPDATE</button>
    </td>
</tr>  
';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add `if` inside a string.

```
<?php
if ($row["gender"] == "Male") {
    $gender = '<option value="Male" selected>Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option>';
} else {
    $gender = '<option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female" selected>Female</option>';
} 

$output .= '  
<tr class="datas">  
        <td class="id" data-id10="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["id"].'</td>
        <td class="firstname" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["firstname"].'</td>  
        <td class="middlename" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["middlename"].'</td>  
        <td class="lastname" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["lastname"].'</td> 
        <td class="address" data-id4="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["address"].'</td> 
        <td class="gender" data-id5="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>

        <select onchange="getval(this)">' . $gender . '</select>

        </td> 

        <td class="contact" data-id6="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["contact"].'</td> 
        <td class="username" data-id7="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["username"].'</td> 
        <td class="password" data-id8="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["password"].'</td> 

        <td class="but"><button type="button" name="delete_btn" id="delete_btn" data-id9="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">DELETE</button>
        <button type="button" name="delete_btn" id="update_btn" data-id12="'.$row["id"].'">UPDATE</button>
        </td>';
```

You can use this too:

```
<?php

$output .= '
<tr class="datas">  
    <td class="id" data-id10="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["id"].'</td>
    <td class="firstname" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["firstname"].'</td>  
    <td class="middlename" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["middlename"].'</td>  
    <td class="lastname" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["lastname"].'</td> 
    <td class="address" data-id4="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["address"].'</td> 
    <td class="gender" data-id5="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>

    <select onchange="getval(this)">' . $row["gender"] == "Male" ? '<option value="Male" selected>Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option>' : '<option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female" selected>Female</option>' . '</select>

    </td> 

    <td class="contact" data-id6="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["contact"].'</td> 
    <td class="username" data-id7="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["username"].'</td> 
    <td class="password" data-id8="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["password"].'</td> 

    <td class="but"><button type="button" name="delete_btn" id="delete_btn" data-id9="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">DELETE</button>
    <button type="button" name="delete_btn" id="update_btn" data-id12="'.$row["id"].'">UPDATE</button>
    </td>
</tr>';
```